# Is there a way to hide images but show text when the user wants to print a page?

Tags: html, css, text, printing

I am creating a print css file. I am trying to hide the header image div on the top of the page but keep the text inside it. I don't want there to be a space left for the div on the page. This is going to be a print file.

HTML

```
<div class="module_hero">
    <div class="image hero">
        <div class="gradient">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p class="blurb">Blurb</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add styles to remove the background image from your `div`s inside a `print` media query like so:

```css
@media print {
  .module_hero, .image.hero, .gradient {
    background: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="module_hero">
    <div class="image hero">
        <div class="gradient">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <p class="blurb">Blurb</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes to the above, but if you want to make sure the `.image.hero` div does not occupy any space on the page, you may also need to add a `display:none;` for that CSS class.